# Create pivot table from 3 tables using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, union-all, tableau-desktop

I am trying to join three tables to then create a pivot table. I'm struggling to find figure out how to do this.

Below is an example of the format of the three existing tables and the desired out output table.

I am working in Tableau and the data is feeding in from a Microsoft SQL server.

**Contact Table** (Table 1)

| Contact ID | Name | Channel | Contact Type | Stage 1 | Stage 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12098 | Andrew | Google | Client | 44593 | 44597 |
| 34556 | Joe | Facebook | Client | 44568 | 44576 |
| 32344 | Paul | Indeed | Buyer |  |  |
| 32211 | Simon | Indeed | Client | 44562 | 44570 |
| 21212 | Peter | Facebook | Client | 44599 | 44601 |
| 29871 | Sam | Google | Client | 44611 | 44613 |

**Contact/Deal Association** (Table 2)

| Deal ID | Contact ID |
| --- | --- |
| 543 | 12098 |
| 232 | 34556 |
| 456 | 32211 |
| 787 | 21212 |
| 654 | 29871 |

**Deal History** (Table 3)

| Deal ID | Stage 3 | Stage 4 | Stage 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 543 | 44599 | 44601 |  |
| 232 | 44582 | 44593 | 44599 |
| 456 | 44580 |  |  |
| 787 | 44610 | 44612 | 44615 |
| 654 | 44615 |  |  |

**Pivot Table** (Output Table)

| Contact ID | Pivot Name | Pivot Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12098 | Stage 1 | 44593 |
| 12098 | Stage 2 | 44597 |
| 12098 | Stage 3 | 44599 |
| 12098 | Stage 4 | 44601 |
| 34556 | Stage 1 | 44568 |
| 34556 | Stage 2 | 44576 |
| 34556 | Stage 3 | 44582 |
| 34556 | Stage 4 | 44593 |
| 34556 | Stage 5 | 44599 |
| 32211 | Stage 1 | 44562 |
| 32211 | Stage 2 | 44570 |
| 32211 | Stage 3 | 44580 |
| 21212 | Stage 1 | 44599 |
| 21212 | Stage 2 | 44601 |
| 21212 | Stage 3 | 44610 |
| 21212 | Stage 4 | 44612 |
| 21212 | Stage 5 | 44615 |
| 29871 | Stage 1 | 44611 |
| 29871 | Stage 2 | 44613 |
| 29871 | Stage 3 | 44615 |

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please remove the image and add data as text, tag which dbms are you using

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Looks more like unpivot. Yes, UNION ALL is a good idea.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have now updated it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution , but this might work for you:

```
select ContactID,
       PivotName,
       PivotValue                 
FROM (
       select ContactID,max(Stage1) as Stage1,max(Stage2) as Stage2,max(Stage3) as Stage3,max(Stage4) as Stage4,max(Stage5) as Stage5
          from (
                  select cd.ContactID,c.Stage1,null as Stage2,null as Stage3,null as Stage4,null as Stage5
                  from  Contact_deal cd inner join DealHistory dh on dh.DealID=cd.DealID inner join Contact c on c.ContactID=cd.ContactID
                  union all
                  select cd.ContactID,null as Stage1,c.Stage2,null as Stage3,null as Stage4,null as Stage5
                  from  Contact_deal cd inner join DealHistory dh on dh.DealID=cd.DealID inner join Contact c on c.ContactID=cd.ContactID
                  union all
                  select cd.ContactID,null as Stage1,null as Stage2,dh.Stage3,null as Stage4,null as Stage5
                  from  Contact_deal cd inner join DealHistory dh on dh.DealID=cd.DealID inner join Contact c on c.ContactID=cd.ContactID
                  union all
                  select cd.ContactID,null as Stage1,null as Stage2,null as Stage3,dh.Stage4,null as Stage5
                  from  Contact_deal cd inner join DealHistory dh on dh.DealID=cd.DealID inner join Contact c on c.ContactID=cd.ContactID
                  union all
                  select cd.ContactID,c.Stage1,null as Stage2,null as Stage3,null as Stage4,dh.Stage5
                  from  Contact_deal cd inner join DealHistory dh on dh.DealID=cd.DealID inner join Contact c on c.ContactID=cd.ContactID 
                 )  t1 group by ContactID 
      ) t2 
unpivot
(
  PivotValue
  for PivotName in (Stage1,Stage2,Stage3,Stage4,Stage5)
) unpiv;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> ContactID  PivotName  PivotValue
>   12098     Stage1     44593
>   12098     Stage2     44597
>   12098     Stage3     44599
>   12098     Stage4     44601
>   21212     Stage1     44599
>   21212     Stage2     44601
>   21212     Stage3     44610
>   21212     Stage4     44612
>   21212     Stage5     44615
>   29871     Stage1     44611
>   29871     Stage2     44613
>   29871     Stage3     44615
>   32211     Stage1     44562
>   32211     Stage2     44570
>   32211     Stage3     44580
>   34556     Stage1     44568
>   34556     Stage2     44576
>   34556     Stage3     44582
>   34556     Stage4     44593
>   34556     Stage5     44599
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70b21c45961d446030ce43ac926bbc11)

Comment: The question is about UNPIVOT and not PIVOT, so this is the best solution for me as well!

Comment: @ergestbasha thank you so much - after a few iteration and some adjustments your solution worked perfectly. Thanks again. Much appreciated.